# How Can I Get the Page To AutoRefresh So The User Does Not Need To Press A Button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a type of calculator that the user does not need to press a submit button.

I want the page to be able automatically change the value. So for example, If the output of 6+10 is 16, I want that, when the user changes the values to 6+11, it will automatically change to 17.

Comment: something like this? http://aljonngo.blogspot.com/2015/05/real-time-calculator-using-jquery.html

Comment: Yes, but what if I didn't want to use the buttons at the bottom? So, for example, if i did V=IR and the V, I, R were fields on it's own with just the submit button. 

Would I do the same thing for that?

Comment: It's all very simple to do, you can make a submit button activate the change, change the name of one of those buttons `+ , -, x, /` to the name `submit` and you will have a submit button.. if you want it  to be done with no buttons.. it is defaulted to `+` which is the same as no buttons you can just remove all buttons and it will function as a `+` then you can change the `+` to whatever you like  `keyup` is used to detect you press any button (number) in a textbox and `click` is used to detect you clicked on a button.. thats all you really need to know.. those 2 commands. sums() is the drawer

Comment: If you want give me a URL to your sample page.. that's not functioning and I will fix it for you.

Comment: @SSpoke I figured it out, thank you though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is exactly what you want, full code and you can run it on the bottom.

```js
    $( document ).ready(function() {
     $( ".1st" ).keyup(function() {
      var1s = $( ".1st" ).val();      
      if(var1s.match(/^\d+$/)){
       $('.messageError').html('');
       sums();      
      }else{
       $('.messageError').html('sorry number only for the first value');      
      }     
     });
     
     $( ".2nd" ).keyup(function() {
      var2s = $( ".2nd" ).val();      
      if(var2s.match(/^\d+$/)){
       $('.messageError').html('');
       sums();      
      }else{
       $('.messageError').html('sorry number only for the second value');      
      }     
     });     
     
       
     $( ".add" ).click(function() {     
      $('.operator').html('+'); 
      sums();      
     });
     $( ".minus" ).click(function() {
      $('.operator').html('-'); 
      sums();     
     });
     $( ".times" ).click(function() {
      $('.operator').html('x');
      sums();     
     });
     $( ".divide" ).click(function() {
      $('.operator').html('/');
      sums();     
     });    
     
     function sums(){  
      //console.log('testtest');
      var1 =  parseInt($( ".1st" ).val()); 
      var2 =  parseInt($( ".2nd" ).val()); 
      operator = $( ".operator" ).html();   
       sum = (var1 + var2);
      switch (operator) { 
       case '+': 
        sum = (var1 + var2);
        break;
       case '-': 
        sum = (var1 - var2);
        break;
       case 'x': 
        sum = (var1 * var2);
        break;  
       case '/': 
        sum = (var1 / var2);
        break;
       default:
        sum = (var1 + var2);
      }     
       $( ".answer" ).html(sum);
       
        $(".answer").each(function(c, obj){
         $(obj).text(addCommas(parseFloat($(obj).text()).toFixed(2)));
         });    
     }
     
     function addCommas(nStr)
     {
        nStr += '';
        x = nStr.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
        }
        return x1 + x2;
     }      
    });
```

```css
    .add, .minus, .times,.divide{
     display:block;
     width:20px;
     height:20px;
     border:1px solid #333;
     float:left;
     text-align:center;
     cursor:pointer;
     margin-left:10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainContainer">   
     <div class="messageError"></div>
       
     <form>     
      <input type="text" class="1st" name="1st">  
      <span class="operator">+</span>
      <input type="text" class="2nd" name="2nd"> 
      <span> = </span>
      <span class="answer"></span>
     </form> 
      </br>      
     <div>
      <span class="add">+</span>
      <span class="minus">-</span>
      <span class="times">x</span>
      <span class="divide">/</span>     
     </div>    
    </div>
```